# Flex DateTimeAxis not showing labels

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a chart that uses a DateTimeAxis for the x-axis and a renderer defined for it.  I also have a function defined for the label on the axis but I am not able to get the labels to show.

Trying to print out a static time to test working.

```
private function timeAxisLabelFunction(obj1:Object, obj2:Object, axis:IAxis):String
{
    return "9:30AM";
}


<mx:AreaChart
        id="alertVolumeChart"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        dataProvider="{volumes}"
        showDataTips="true" >
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:DateTimeAxis id="xAxis" 
                 dataUnits="minutes"
                 baseAtZero="false"
                 alignLabelsToUnits="false"
                 interval="8" 
                 minorTickInterval="1" 
                 labelFunction="timeAxisLabelFunction"/>

    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer 
            id="hAxisRenderer" canDropLabels="false"
                        axis="{xAxis}" showLabels="true"
                        labelFunction="timeRendererLabelFunction"
                        minorTickLength="8" minorTickPlacement="outside"
                        tickLength="20" tickPlacement="outside"
                        labelAlign="right" labelGap="4"
                        tickStroke="{timeStroke}" minorTickStroke="{timeStroke}" axisStroke="{timeStroke}" >
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:series>
        <mx:AreaSeries
            yField="value" xField="time">   
        </mx:AreaSeries>        
    </mx:series>

</mx:AreaChart>
```

Update:

Apparently, the font family I was using doesnt support a font style that is used in the renderer.  Not sure what style attribute it is yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the font family i was trying to use.  It was not compatible with the renderer so I needed to embed the same font again but with embedAsCFF: false;